# In pandas, how can I choose the curve color in a plot based on MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex dataframe like this one

```
             Freights            Passengers
Station      Hogwarts              Hogwarts
Direction  Northbound Southbound Northbound Southbound
Date
2020-04-10          0          1          0          9
2020-04-11          0          2          0          8
2020-04-12          5          3         15         17
2020-04-13          6          4          4         26
```

I would like to get a plot with a curve for each column, the `Freights` columns should be red while the `Passengers` should be blue.

I have managed to get the result as in the following snippet but I would like to know whether there is a more idiomatic way (for example avoiding the for-loop) of doing it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-04-10', '2020-04-11', '2020-04-12', '2020-04-13','2020-04-10', '2020-04-11', '2020-04-12', '2020-04-13'],
'Station': ['Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts','Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts', 'Hogwarts'],
'Direction': ['Southbound', 'Southbound', 'Southbound', 'Southbound','Northbound','Northbound','Northbound','Northbound'],
'Daily trains': [10,10,20,30,0,0,20,10],
'Freights': [1,2,3,4,0,0,5,6],
'Passengers': [9,8,17,26,0,0,15,4]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%Y-%m-%d")

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns=['Station','Direction'],values=['Freights','Passengers'])
colors = {'Freights':'red','Passengers':'blue'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for i in df1:
    df1[i].plot(ax=ax,color=colors[i[0]])

ax.figure.savefig('so.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: not sure what you are looking for, but `df1.plot(color=df1.columns.get_level_values(0).map(colors))` kind of give similar result

Comment: @Ben.T That's ok for me, I've updated the questions, for example I would like to avoid the for-loop.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson - use BenT's statement in place of your for loop.